# How a live event video is ingested to a streaming platform for broadcasting live?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

Please help me in understanding how live media is sent from the encoder (media source) in real time to the streaming platform for broadcasting live to multiple viewers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions. RTMP is most common for UGC, with SRT and RIST the new kids on the block. But professional content could use zixi, rtp, rtsp, ts over UDP or even satellite uplink.

Comment: SRT & RIST have feedback mechanism, what is the approx end to end delay these protocol should ideally have, if we are using for broadcasting? Any idea or reference.

Comment: end to end? as in glass to glass? If you are using normal internet distribution (HLS/DASH), 90% of the delay will be in the delivery side. The contribution side is nearly irrelevant by comparison.

Comment: end to end means - From Media Source to the Media Server. I am looking at the  SRT & RIST only ( the delay can be in  ??? milliseconds ) . I am aware of the HLS/DASH Streaming Delay.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. Is there any open source implementation of RTMP protocol for media server ?